# What's the difference between a const list and unmodifiable List?

Tags: dart

I can't add/delete/modify elements in a const list and in an unmodifiable list. So, what's the difference between the two if they both are doing the same thing?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I'm the one who was confused.  Unlike C++, Dart has no notion of "const methods" and cannot at compilation-time determine what methods are allowed to be called on `const` objects.

Comment: @jamesdlin No worries sir, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference because, slightly exaggerated, there is no "const list".

In Dart, being constant is not a property of a value, it's a property of an *expression*.

Example:

```dart
class Foo {
  final int x;
  const Foo(this.x);
}
main() {
  var foo1 = const Foo(1);
  var foo2 = new Foo(1);
  print(isConstant(foo1)); // cannot be done.
}
```

There is no way to write a general `isConstant` function which can distinguish an object created using `const` from one created using `new`.
The run-time system has a list of the const-created objects somewhere (because it needs that to canonicalize another `const Foo(1)` to the same value), but the *value itself* doesn't know that it was created using a `const` expression.

List literals are slightly different from constructor based object creation because a non-const literal is mutable and a const literal is not.
Instead the `const` literal creates a list object similar to the one you would create using `List.unmodifiable`.
And again, the list object itself doesn't know whether it was created using `const [...]` or `List.unmodifiable([...])`, it just knows that it's an unmodifiable list with a specific set of values.

The VM actually uses the same class for both const lists and unmodifiable lists (dart2js uses JS Array for everything, but does mark them the same way as fixed-length and unmodifiable). The compilers didn't have to use the same class, it's an implementation detail how `const` lists are implemented, but it's also not surprising that they only have one implementation of an unmodifiable list, anything else would be wasteful.

So, there is no difference between a const list object and a list created using `List.unmodifiable`. They're instances of the same implementation class.

(Obviously, a constant *variable* holding a constant list can be used in other constant expressions, and constant list literals are canonicalized, so if you write `const [1]` two places in the program, it evaluates to the same list object, but the *object itself* is just an unmodifiable list).

Comment: Now, I got the point, thank you sir for writing it in detail. Can you please tell me where can I find these nuances of Dart? It's no where mentioned in the docs (I think)

Comment: I'm not sure it's written down anywhere except the language specification, and the actual implementations. The spec states that creating a `const Foo(1)` uses the same operations as `new Foo(1)`, then afterwards it checks whether there is already another `Foo` object created by a `const` construction with the same object state, and if so, uses that instead (canonicalization). For lists, it really is an implementation detail which class an implementation uses for a `const` list, and the library `List.unmodifiable` constructor has no definition other than its declaration. No *promises* made.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference. When you're using `const` for a `List`, you can only add constant values. However, this is not the case with an unmodifiable list.

```dart
var foo = 1;
const l1 = [foo]; // Compile-time error
final l2 = List.unmodifiable([foo]); // No error
```

Answer (score 1):

Another important difference is two equal `const` objects are guaranteed to be identical (so they points to the same internal object since the object is built on compile time) where two unmodifiable lists will always be two different objects:

```
void main() {
  final unmodifiableList1 = List<int>.unmodifiable(<int>[1,2,3]);
  final unmodifiableList2 = List<int>.unmodifiable(<int>[1,2,3]);
  print(identical(unmodifiableList1, unmodifiableList2)); // false

  const constList1 = [1,2,3];
  const constList2 = [1,2,3];
  print(identical(constList1, constList2)); // true
}
```